# How to use a binary tree with multiple duplicated key values or other alternative

Tags: java, data-structures, binary-tree, treemap

I am working on a project using Java where I am retrieving data about movies from a movie store website. So I`m given a rating number x (integer from 0 to 5) and a category y ("horror", for example). I have to return movies with minimum rating x from the y category. On top of that I must use a data structure that would not iterate through every movie to retrieve this data.

So firstly I thought of implementing a **binary tree to every category**, where the key would be the rating (from 0 to 5). So in this situation I would have some duplicated keys, but the values would be added anyway to the tree. It seemed to work at first, but I got stucked in something: if I want to retrieve movies with minimum rating x and there is just one movie with the rating x (it is a leaf of the tree), I can not find a way to retrieve the others >= x movies.

I also tried TreeMap from Java. But it does not allow duplicated keys, so it would not work on this project.

Can someone help me? I would love some suggestions on how to solve the issue on the binary tree. Or other alternative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Binary trees, in general, may or may not support duplicate keys, it depends on the implementation details. If you are using an implementation which does not support duplicate keys, such as the *TreeMap* in Java, you have still several options.

**Use multimaps**

There is a structure called *Multimap* which allows storing multiple values  per key. You can store a tree of categories, as you do now, and then a **multimap** by rating for every category (instead of a **map**, as you are doing now). There is no multimap implementation in the standard java collections, but there are zillons of open-source implementations available. [For example Google Guava Multimap.](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html)

**Use a composite key**

Store all movies in a single TreeMap, using a composite key - a triple of (Category, Rating, GeneratedUniqueIntegerForDisambiguation). The comparator would compare first the category, if they are the same, then the rating, and if they are still the same, then the generated int.

Treemap supports efficient interval queries *subMap(fromKey, toKey)*. So the horros with rating at least 3 could be retrieved like this:

```
map.submap(new MyKey("horror", 3, Integer.MIN_VALUE), new MyKey("horror", 5, Integer.MAX_VALUE))
```

Comment: What would this GeneratedUniqueIntegerForDisambiguation be? How can I generate it? And in the example you use Integer.MIN_VALUE and Integer.MAX_VALUE. Why?

Comment: It's just some unique thing, because the key for the TreeMap must be unique, and just the category plus rating are not. If your movie record has a unique ID field, you can use it. Otherwise you can just generate a sequence 1,2,3...

Comment: I used Integer.MIN_VALUE and Integer.MAX_VALUE because you are interested only in the category and rating in the query. The third part does not matter here. So Integer.MIN_VALUE is a natural value for the lower bound and , MAX_VALUE for the upper bound.

Comment: Ok, I see. It turned out I'm using the google guava multimap solution. Thanks a lot for the help! :)